# How do I use javascript to change the font colour on my webpage?

Tags: javascript, fonts, colors, attributes

I can't use JQuery sadly I need to use good old Javascript.

I have a forum and a black theme and when people use black text on it you can't see it. So I want to use javascript to change all the black text on the page to white when the page loads.

Comment: Won't CSS be more suitable for this?

Comment: As Yi Jiang mentioned, CSS would be the best approach, then you change the className property on each element to be affected in javascript.

Comment: Thanks but the user defines their own colours within their own posts. I don't want to change ALL colours to white. JUST black text. I need a way to highlight all black text on the back and change it ti white and nothing else.

Comment: @user CSS would still work. Depending on how you implement it, but it is most likely that the global font color (`body`) will be `#fff`, while the user defined colors will have more specificity which will override this global color.

Comment: *How* are users defining text colors? Are you giving them a WYSIWYG editor that spits out inline styles? Or...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answerers have posted JavaScript solutions if you really want to use JS for this, so I won't add another. However, I just thought I'd offer two alternatives:

- If you find that black is the default color for any posts, and you can modify your theme, don't use JavaScript for this — open your theme's CSS file, try to locate the style that makes post text black, and change it to white.
- If black text is simply caused by people changing the color to be such in their own posts, I think a better idea would be to just tell your members not to use black text. I can also see legitimate uses of black text on black backgrounds, e.g. for a lack of spoiler tags in your forum software.

Answer (score 3):

```
document.body.style.color = '#555555'
```

of course then you have to use the `getElementById`function instead of body if you want to select a specific element.

That's not really smart though. Go with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to dynamically change your theme/styles you can use javascript to disable and enable css link element in the head by selecting link tags via document.getElementsByTagName("link")